# Replace NAs by Interpolation in groups

Tags: r

I want to know how to replace `NA` values in a specific column by groups with an interpolation. Some of my groups only have one non-NA I would like to fill those groups with the one non-NA

If I have a dataframe like:

```
Group Value
ALB     NA
ALB     10
ALB     NA
ALB     12
ARE     NA
ARE     NA
ARE     2
ARE     NA
ARE     NA
ARG     4
ARG     NA
ARG     6
```

I want to create a new column, so my dataframe would look like the following:

```
Group Value New Column
ALB     NA    9
ALB     10    10
ALB     NA    11
ALB     12    12
ARE     NA    2
ARE     NA    2
ARE     2     2
ARE     NA    2
ARE     NA    2
ARG     4     4
ARG     NA    5
ARG     6     6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one-liner will interpolate the NAs by group and for NAs on the ends of a group will extend the nearest non-NA to it giving it the same value, i.e. it does linear interpolation and constant extrapolation, which is not exactly what was asked for but may be close enough.  Note that this also implies that if there is only one non-NA then all NAs are set to it.

```
library(zoo)
transform(DF, newCol = ave(Value, Group, FUN = function(x) na.approx(x, rule = 2)))
```

giving:

```
   Group Value newCol
1    ALB    NA     10
2    ALB    10     10
3    ALB    NA     11
4    ALB    12     12
5    ARE    NA      2
6    ARE    NA      2
7    ARE     2      2
8    ARE    NA      2
9    ARE    NA      2
10   ARG     4      4
11   ARG    NA      5
12   ARG     6      6
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Value = c(NA, 
10L, NA, 12L, 4L, NA, NA, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

DF <- 
  structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
  2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ALB", "ARE", "ARG"), class = "factor"), 
  Value = c(NA, 10L, NA, 12L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 4L, NA, 6L
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is close, but is there a way to make the groups that only have one non-NA to have the non-NA for all observations? (I edited my question to show my problem properly)

Comment: The code already does that since in that case all NAs are at the ends.  I have replaced the original data frame in the Note with the one in the modified question and show the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(1:2, each = 4), 
  value = c(NA, 10, NA, 12, 4, NA, NA, 7))

complete <- function(x){
  i <- which.min(is.na(x))
  y <- seq_along(x) + x[i] - i
  return(y)
}

newdf <- do.call(rbind, 
                 lapply(split(df, df$group), 
                        function(dat){
                          transform(dat, newvalue=complete(value))
                        }))
rownames(newdf) <- NULL
```

This gives:

```
> newdf
  group value newvalue
1     1    NA        9
2     1    10       10
3     1    NA       11
4     1    12       12
5     2     4        4
6     2    NA        5
7     2    NA        6
8     2     7        7
```

Comment: Thanks, in my actual data frame group is country codes, its therefore not numbers but letters (so ALB, ARE,...) and I have over a thousand observations, is there a way I can not write all of the observations down, like you did it in this code?

Comment: @ArOk This code should work even if the groups are letters.

Comment: Also please change the question to indicate this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `na.approx` in `zoo` package:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-2/topics/na.approx

You can use `split` on your data and then use `apply`.

```
 > library(zoo)
 > df<- data.frame(
      group = rep(1:2, each = 4), 
      value = c(NA, 10, NA, 12, 4, NA, NA, 7))
 > df
     group value
 1     1    NA
 2     1    10
 3     1    NA
 4     1    12
 5     2     4
 6     2    NA
 7     2    NA
 8     2     7
 > dfl <- split(df$value, df$group)
 > dfl
   $`1`
   [1] NA 10 NA 12

   $`2`
   [1]  4 NA NA  7

 > lapply(dfl, na.approx)
   $`1`
   [1] 10 11 12

   $`2`
   [1] 4 5 6 7
```

However, this will work if you have upper and lower limit in each group. Otherwise you will have issue like in the first group where it couldn't determine what to replace NA with.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a few things now but I always run into the error "unused argument (New Column = 1:1283)"

Comment: I ended up trying those three lines ( and some small variations of them)  #1 na.approx(AB, read_trend = index(AB))  
#2 na.approx(AB, read_trend = index(AB), 'Country Code', na.rm = TRUE, along)  
#3 na.approx(AB, read_trend = index(AB), AB$read_trend, na.rm = TRUE, maxgap = 10)   ' I got the unused argument error twice (for #1&#3) and "x and index must have the same length" once (#2)

Answer (score 0):

One can consider using `Hmisc::approxExtrap` function to perform both `interpolate` and `extrapolate` missing values. You have to provide both `x` and `y` values without `NA` which will be used as `reference` to `interpolate/extrapolate` missing values. The function returns for required set/rows (as passed with argument `xout`) after `interpolating/extrapolating`.

```
library(Hmisc)
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(Group) %>%
mutate(newVal = 
approxExtrap(which(!is.na(Value)), Value[!is.na(Value)],xout = 1:n(), rule=2)$y) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   Group Value newVal
# 1     1    NA      9
# 2     1    10     10
# 3     1    NA     11
# 4     1    12     12
# 5     2     4      4
# 6     2    NA      5
# 7     2    NA      6
# 8     2     7      7
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text =
"Group Value
1     NA
1     10
1     NA
1     12
2     4
2     NA
2     NA
2     7",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am getting this error now "need at least two non-NA values to interpolate" one in at least one of my groups there is only one value is that the problem?

Comment: @ArOk Thats true. You need at least 2 `non-NA` values in order to interpolate or extrapolate. Otherwise it will not work. You can think how to predict if minimum 2 values are not present.

Comment: @ArOk I can think of one option. You can exclude `groups` which has got only 1 `non-NA` values. Then apply `approximation` function. Let me know if that be of any help to you and accordingly I will guide you on how to get it done.